# Twilio Client taking call on hold

Tags: php, javascript, twilio

I am working on a voip system supposed to work like this:

- i call a number with twilio client
- Talk to other party and when necessary hit a button to take him on hold music

i call the number like this inside twilio client:

```
Twilio.Device.connect({"call": num});
```

then store the call details in database. when twilio responds to twiml url, the databse record is updated with callsid so i can access it to modify the call.

at this point when i want to take the call on hold, on server side i use:

```
$client->account->calls->get($callSid)->update("CurrentUrl", 'hold.xml');
```

the problem is, when i run the line above. the other party disconnects and i am taken on hold music instead of him.

how can i make sure he doesnt disconnect and go on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the REST API documentation?

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

Although, I think changing URL may change the URL for all parties... Have a look and let me know how you get on. If I have some time later I'll try and replicate.

Comment: I have tried some variations but no matter what other party hangs up when i update the twiml url. i am a beginner on twilio api. it is frusturating and i would really apreciate your help on this. thank you.

Comment: Strange. Maybe join the Twilio IRC room during their "Office Hours" - basically a few staff members join for questions / help. Saying that, there's usually someone from staff in there most times.

http://www.twilio.com/blog/twilio-live-chat-irc.html

Office Hours are Tuesdays from 10am-Noon PT and Thursdays from 4-6pm PT. If you're in SF you can visit the office in person on Thursdays...